# Laptop electrical protection overseas

Tags: security, power-supply

I will be carrying my laptop on holiday overseas to India soon. The place I will be living at may not have earthing in all of their power sockets. Is this something I should be worried about? Should I take an extra surge protection adapter with me, or would the little charger block (not sure what its called) provided with the laptop be sufficient protection for it?

Answer (score 3):

Results will vary vastly with area and circumstance. I'm told that in many areas in India power is often unavailable for substantial periods on a daily basis. Those are the sorts of conditions where brownouts typically occur and I understand that surges and spikes are common in much of the Indian power system. (I recently spent 3 weeks in India with a laptop and my wife has been there for about 10 weeks- neither of us had any problems - but a sample of 2 is of no more than anecdotal value).

Even though I didn't, I'd recommend using a reputable brand single outlet MOV based protector with the manufacturer stating that the protection is available without an input ground - see below for details. I'd expect to pay $US20 or less.

Earthing is not the main issue - rather it's protection against surges, spikes and brownouts.

The ability to resist the affects of "bad power" depends on the design and manufacture of the adaptor used and will depend on brand and model. If the manufacturer does not specify and/or guarantee the ability to survive bad power conditions then and after-market protector can be compact and not overly expensive.

Brownout - the operation of mains for long periods at substantially lower than normal voltages (say under 90VAC for a 110 VAC device) - can be lethally dangerous for some appliances, such as those with electric motors such as refrigerators, if they have not specifically protected against this. Computer switching power supplies which are designed to be "universal" and to operate on from well below 110 VAC to well above 230 VAC SHOULD be less susceptible to brownout. Ensure that your power supply is a universal one with a wide input operating voltage range. This is liable to be easier to deal with in India than in some countries as nominal mains voltage is around 230 VAC, so a brownout condition of 210 or 200 or even 150 Volts (!!!!) would still be inside the eg 90-260 VAC range of a universal power supply.

Spikes and surges are relatively easily dealt with by the use of a good quality line filter from a reputable manufacturer. As you are specifically concerned about line to line surges in the absence of an input ground connection, seeing what the manufacturer says about such conditions may be useful. Expect most low cost no-name units to provide no information - they should still be OK. Reputable manufacturers will either cover it in a spec sheet or be prepared to comment.

Some surge protectors carry guarantees of payment of a significant sum of money if damage occurs to equipment when the filter is in use. Such a guarantee is worthwhile not so much for the "prize" if failure occurs, but as a demonstration of the manufacturer's confidence in their product. One of the well known makers of such warranteed devices is Belkin (who I have no involvement with - I've just been exposed to enough of their ads over the years to recall they are in the market). Their other products are usually not total junk - worth a look.

Most surge protectors use MOVs - Metal Oxide Varistors - to absorb surges. These change in characteristics with each surge absorbed and do wear out. You want a 230 VAC rated one for Indian use. A 110 VAC rated one will probably die instantly on 230 VAC. 
Look for the highest Joule (energy) absorption rating per $ paid. For ground-free operation the MOVs need to be connected line to line (active to neutral / phase to neutral). If they are ONLY connected line to ground on both legs it will still work but with double the voltage rating.  Reputable manufacturers will be able to comment on this.

You can pay vast sums for such equipment - over $500 in some cases. This is unlikely to be justified for protection purposes in ANY case (unless you swear by Oxygen free copper cables and crystal lattice resonant Q cells and ...). You should be able to buy a suitable unit for $20 or less.

Here's a was $30 now $20 [Belkin unit rated at 3500 Joule](http://www.belkin.com/us/BSQ800-06-Belkin/p/P-BSQ800-06%3bjsessionid=FF4FECA8BBC3B8339EFF7B9097AFE18E/). The same shop sells 2000 and 2500 Joule Belkin units at the same price. This is physically too large for carrying around the world. You should be able to get a small single outlet unit with similar energy rating. You can "roll your own" by placing multiple MOVs across the mains in an adaptor of your choice. You can get vastly more protection per $ this way but need to be competent at doing such work.

Here is a [less than happy Belkin customer report](http://www.itwire.com/opinion-and-analysis/whiskey-tango-foxtrot/58022-belkin-when-is-a-warranty-not-a-warranty) BUT the complaint seems to be more with responsiveness BUT the device did not survive a lightning strike. (**Nothing** will, worst case).

Here's a lawyer reporting on both apparently poor performance and devious fine print from a [failed Staples brand protector](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/261556-28-surge-collecting-surge-protector-warranty)

Brands I've seen mentioned include Panamax, Monster, APC, Sunfire, ... .
You can read "Panamax is best and pay out on their warranty" claims on one page and probably just the opposite elsewhere. Due diligence required.

[Panamax](http://pfpower.com/Training/Video/index.php?video=3)

[Surgex](http://www.surgex.com/)

[Demonstration of affect on TV with and without protector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzG7A9m1Sys)

I've emailed user AG who lives in India and is liable to provide an on-the-spot comment on my suggestions and may wish to provide a better answer.

Comment: Simple: A typical universal-power (90-250V) laptop adapter does not have an earthing conductor anyway on the wall side, and works perfectly well in Indian conditions. The laptop is well protected by the adapter. Of course, in "load shedding" power outage conditions, any laptop adapter works just as well as any other.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh :-) :-) :-). I have seen discussions elsewhere that suggest that people have had significant problems on Indian power systems with spikes etc. Of course, in a country of about 1 billion people, "Indian power systems" and "some people" are 'not guaranteed'\ to be representative. | I'd expect that under conditions where voltage fluctuated widely and rapidly over a significant while (brownout) that some adaptors may be more troubled than others - I'd expect eg a Toshiba supply (made in China) to better ride the storm that a very low cost no name brand supply. I may be disappointed :-